# Should I answer an effortless but clear question?

Tags: discussion, answers

I see some questions like "how do I do this?" but shows no effort was made by the OP. Just a problem and the desired result. While I know this is bad questioning, because StackOverflow is not a solution giving site, maybe I **do** have the patient and free time to give the OP what they are asking.

But should I?

Comment: I actually don't really like the "code tax" that some people seem to demand. I mean somebody comes in and says "I have this, I need that" and they immediately get a comment to the effect of "what have you tried?". Yes, SO is *not* a code writing service, literally coming in and going "I have `[1, 2, 3]`, I want to get `6`" is super low effort and shouldn't be answered. However, if the user laboriously explained all requirements, included examples of input, multiple expected outputs, also examples of what's NOT expected, then that's still *effort*, even if there is no code involved.

Comment: @VLAZ: those are exceedingly rare. The pattern "1. *my requirements*, 2. ???, 3. Profit" is still way too common. My usual pattern is "So what did you try?", followed by a close vote around a day later – even if there are answers.

Comment: @usr2564301 oh, I didn't want to suggest they are *common*. Yes, the vast majority are "write a sorting function for me" or the like. Looking at the regex tag is even worse. However, questions with effort in them but no code do appear from time to time. Yet they too get slapped with the same code tax. I just tend to VTC low effort ones as "needs more focus" since it expects us to do everything.

Comment: If I understand the requirements correctly there's only really a "code tax" on homework, debugging and "I need SQL"-Questions.

Comment: I think the discussion is falling back to whether or not a user has put effort in a question. That was not my intention. I am asking what should be MY behavior as a user that likes to give answers. If I see a question that didn't show much effort (take a Regex question, for exemple), is it wrong if I give it an answer? I have the free time, the patience, and I actually enjoy doing so. But am I making the site somehow worse by giving answer to a clear but effortless question?

Comment: @PedroLima if you disagree with the post being closed as duplicate please follow standard https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not/194495#194495 to get it re-opened or maybe ask new question on part that is not covered by duplicate. Generally there will be no "discussion" after post closed...